# Is it good to store all the data regarding one user on one large document on mongodb and how the performance and speed will be?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am creating a project that analyze a websites for users and bring all the text inside each page and store it on the mongodb document I am thinking about the structure of the document and I don't know what is the best way to do it as I am new on mongodb, i just thought about this structure of json.

```
{
 "userId": "ObjectId",
 "fullname": "Mohammad Shawahneh",
 "sites": {
   "site1.com": {
     "/page1": [
       {
         "text": "lorem ipsam",
         "score": 95
       },
       {
         "text": "ipsam lorem",
         "score": 90
       }
     ],
     "/page2": [
       {
         "text": "lorem ipsam",
         "score": 95
       }
     ]
   },
   "site2.com": {
     "/page1": [
       {
         "text": "loreem iipsam",
         "score": 80
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

so what data I want to query is that I want to get all the text on specific user->site->page so for example I want to query like this userId(eg 1).sites.site1.com./page1.

considering that:

1. the collection will have user document with id indexed
2. the collection could have thousands of users
3. each user could have many websites
4. each website could have thousands of pages
5. each page could have thousands of text object
6. each text object could have large text

so will the query will be fast or the large document will effect it or it will be affected by another aspect? if it is not a good structure how should I do it considering that I need the query as fast as it could be and with large amount of data.

sorry if I am missing something obvious about NoSql since I am totally new on it and didn't found something that help me about my concern.

Comment: This structure is unindexable. You'll have to scan the entire user object each time. I'd store sites and pages in their own documents.

Comment: thank you for your respond, so if will store the site and pages on another documents how can i make relation between it because i need to get the page1 from the site1.com that the user with id = 1 has, and the nosql is not relational DB

Comment: Easy. `db.pages.find({path: '/page1', user_id: "ObjectId", site_id: "ObjectId"})`

Answer (score 0):

The current structure is not indexable beyond user id, you could use arrays instead which would at least allow you to query by the subdocument fields, though with the limitation you mentioned that also isn't a good idea because:

- 16MB size limit per document
- fragmentation due to big arrays

You can store each page per site in a different collection and then use an aggregation pipeline to achieve a single output from a DB command similar to a relational database.

I threw the following solution together real quick, might need some tweaking to fit your use-case better but it should help you get started at least. https://mongoplayground.net/p/XGztgyRIQ91

Depending on how much text you expect there to be per page you could split those out too.

```js
// Database layout, each key being a collection

db={
  users: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("5fe8185bc06521a6fd8996c9"),
      fullname: "Mohammad Shawahneh",
      
    }
  ],
  sites: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("5fe8185bc06521a6fd8996c8"),
      url: "site1.com",
      name: "Site 1"
    }
  ],
  pages: [
    {
      user: ObjectId("5fe8185bc06521a6fd8996c9"),
      site: ObjectId("5fe8185bc06521a6fd8996c8"),
      page: "/page1",
      texts: [
        {
          text: "lorem ipsam",
          score: 95
        },
        {
          text: "ipsam lorem",
          score: 90
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// Aggregation Pipeline:

db.pages.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user: ObjectId("5fe8185bc06521a6fd8996c9"),
      site: ObjectId("5fe8185bc06521a6fd8996c8"),
      page: "/page1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sites",
      localField: "site",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "site"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$site"
  }
])

// Expected Output

[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "page": "/page1",
    "site": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5fe8185bc06521a6fd8996c8"),
      "name": "Site 1",
      "url": "site1.com"
    },
    "texts": [
      {
        "score": 95,
        "text": "lorem ipsam"
      },
      {
        "score": 90,
        "text": "ipsam lorem"
      }
    ],
    "user": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5fe8185bc06521a6fd8996c9"),
      "fullname": "Mohammad Shawahneh"
    }
  }
]
```

Possible array solution which is at least indexable, but as per the paragraph above, I would not recommend it.

```json
{
    "userId": "ObjectId",
    "fullname": "Mohammad Shawahneh",
    "sites": [{
        "id": "site1.com",
        "pages": [{
                "id": "/page1",
                "texts": [{
                        "text": "lorem ipsam",
                        "score": 95
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "ipsam lorem",
                        "score": 90
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "/page2",
                "texts": [{
                    "text": "ipsam lorem",
                    "score": 95
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```